# Quickest Way To Fold Using Marks

Tags: normal-mode, folding, mark

I've found if do `:set number`, I can fold between specific lines x and y with `xGzfyG` or easier for me `xggzfygg`. That's great but it's a distraction to find the line numbers as is **[visual]zf**. I use marks a lot and know I can do a colon command `:'a,'bfo`. Is there any zf shortcut in normal mode using marks ?

This is not for regular text objects, else I would use one the related motion commands.

Comment: Why not create your own normal mode shortcut? E.g. just using your example command: `:nnoremap <leader>zf :'a,'bfo<cr>`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you. `\zf` is an interesting one as I use 'a and 'b the most but it took me a moment to figure out I needed to do it quickly. The issue of course is the marks may not be a or b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `zf` Normal-mode command takes a motion, and moving to a mark is a valid motion. So `'azf'b` is a valid command to create a new fold in the range between marks `'a` and `'b`, and it's equivalent to `:'a,'bfo`.

Other than that, if you want to dedicate a couple marks (such as `'a` and `'b` in your example) and always use them as beginning and end of the region to fold, then you can create a one or two key mapping to fold the region enclosed by those marks.

Or use a single fixed mark, and the current line as the other boundary in your mapping. For example, use `ma` to mark the beginning, then navigate to where you want the end of the fold and use `zf'a`, or a shorter mapping you create for the `zf'a` command.

Comment: This was it and I could not see it. I think I was trying to mix in the g command. Thank you. Upvoted but I don't think it counts.